# Linking GLEW and others, _glViewport is the only unresolved

Tags: c++, opengl, linker, cygwin, glew

I'm using G++ to link my project to glew32, glfw, opengl32, glu32, etc, everything compiles fine - however at the link stage everything but glViewport links and I get this error:

> undefined reference to '_glViewport'.

I find this... odd since everything else was fine and I'm kinda at a loss for what to do. I look forward to any advice on what to try and or do.

Comment: You are passing in the -lGL flag I assume?

Comment: that seemed to solve that problem. I thought I had everything I needed right there - and I hadn't even noticed that one.

Comment: If that fixed it, please post an answer to your question and accept it so that future visitors can see how you were able to resolve this issue.

Comment: Added an answer in hopes that it adds more detail than my quick comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, you need to link with the OpenGL libraries, when you compile do (Linux/cygwin)

```
g++ -o target source.c -lGL
```

To link against the the OpenGL libs on Mac OSX it is

```
g++ -o target source.c -framework OpenGL
```